# How can I have a property in a class to store an picture/image?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I want a attribute in my Hero class to have a Portrait attribute for his/her image. What object type should I use in this case?

```
public class Hero
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HeroType { get; set; }
    public int StartingHP { get; set; }
    public int StartingMana { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Spells { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Items { get; set; }        
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WPF, you should use the [`ImageSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.aspx) class, like this:

```
public class Hero {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HeroType { get; set; }
    public int StartingHP { get; set; }
    public int StartingMana { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Spells { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Items { get; set; } 
    public ImageSource Portrait { get; set; }
}
```

You can read an image from a file like this:

```
myHero.Portrait = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filePath, UriKind.Absolute));
```

<strike>You can use the [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) class from System.Drawing.dll.  For example:</strike>

```
public class Hero {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HeroType { get; set; }
    public int StartingHP { get; set; }
    public int StartingMana { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Spells { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Items { get; set; } 
    public Image Portrait { get; set; }
}
```

To load the image, call `Image.FromFile(path)`.  If you have an image in a stream (eg, from a database or web service, you can call `Image.FromStream(stream)`.

If you have all of the images at compile time, you can put them in a ResX file; you can get an image from the designer-generated code file like this: `myHero.Portrait = SomeResXFile.Portrait1`.

Answer (score 3):

Beware the memory hogging some of the other answers may lead to. This is a data object right, not a UI object?

Do you know for a fact that you will always need the image for the life of the object? I would be concerned about eating up memory. It's probably better to just keep a resource identifier (file path, name in resource file, etc) and only pass that info on to image boxes. I wouldn't suggest holding on to the whole image. In winforms at least (don't know about WPF) the garbage collector isn't so hot at cleaning up images. It only sees them as a reference (i.e. an integer) because the rest of the image is basically an unmanaged object and thinks it's not a high priority for collection. Meanwhile, it could be chewing up megabytes. We got burned on a previous project of mine on that.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

[System.Drawing.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx)